# Backup and Decommission Instance stores in AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vmware

I have inherited some Instance Store-backed Linux AMIs that need to be archived and terminated.  We run a Windows & VMWare environment, so I have little experience with Linux & AWS.

I have tried using the Windows EC2 command line tools to export to a vhdk disk image, but receive an error stating that the instance must be EBS-backed to do so.

What's the easiest way to get a complete backup?  Keep in mind that we have no plans to actually use the instances again, this is just for archival purposes.

Comment: Exporting is generally limited to instances that were imported in the first place. Your best bet is to attach an EBS volume and copy all the data from the instance store to that volume. It may not be able to be booted, but you will have a copy of all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used the `dd` command in combination with ssh to copy images of each relevant drive to offline storage.  Here is a summary of the process:

1. Ssh into the remote machine and run `df -aTh` to figure out which drives to backup
2. Log out of ssh
3. For each desired disk, run the following ssh command to create and download the disk image (changing the `if` path to the desired disk):  `ssh root@[ipaddress] "dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip -1 -" | dd of=outputfile.gz`
4. Wait for the image to fully download.  You may want to examine your network usage and make sure that an appropriate amount of incoming traffic occurs.
5. Double check the disk images for completeness and mount-ability
6. Terminate the Instance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have running instance-store instances (and not AMIs, which would mean you already have a backup), you can still create an AMI.  Its not simple, and may not be worth the effort if you never plan to actually re-launch the instances, but the following page gives you a couple options:

(1) create an instance-store backed AMI from a running instance
(2) subsequently create an EBS-backed AMI from the instance-store AMI

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html

You can also do a sync of the filesystem directly to S3 or attach an EBS volume and copy the files there.